# Frictionless flow in pipes

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I am trying to understand the flow of an ideal, frictionless incompressible fluid through a pipe for these two cases.
[image]

Note: Please consider Flow velocity in the tank is zero, and the fluid is incompressible.

Case 1: This is simple to understand. In this, I can calculate the flow velocity by applying Bernoulli's equation as the pressure difference is completely converted to kinetic energy.

i)So am I correct in understanding that the presence or absence of the pipe has no effect on the flow rate?

ii) Is the pressure at every point of the pipe the same as atmospheric pressure?

Case 2:

iii) Will the flow rate be the same as in case 1 or will the addition of the diverging section cause the flow rate to increase.

iv)Does the inclusion of the diverging section cause the flow to expand and so increase the static pressure (to atmospheric pressure) and if this is true will the static pressure before the expansion be less than atmospheric pressure?

Thank you

Comment: For instantaneous flow, only the pipe diameter(s) and length(s), and fluid properties matter. If being very detailed, the fluid must be accelerated also. Otherwise use basic pipe flow formulas. However if the fluid is truly incompressible and the tank is truly rigid, the pressure difference will rapidly drop, unless P is maintained in the tank by something (which can be wall elasticity or something compressible like air in the tank, or regulator or just gravity)

Comment: @PeteW Assume the pressure and level remain constant what ever the flow in the pipe (infinite tank) and there is no frictional loss..

Comment: by frictionless, do you mean the usual no-slip condition is abandoned completely?

Comment: @PeteW By friction less I mean there are no major or minor losses.

Comment: everything about fluid flow ceases to make sense if no friction exists.  In your example, the only thing allowing the container pressure to be greater than atmospheric would be the inertia of the fluid.

Comment: @TigerGuy So if it's real fluid and if the diffuser is big enough can the pressure in the smaller pipe(upstream of the diffuser) get small enough to cause cavitation?

Comment: @GRANZER cavitation where?

Comment: @TigerGuy in the smaller diameter pipe upstream of the diffuser..in case 2 drawing.(Assume diffuser area can increase without causing seperation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that theoretically you could get liquid to move fast enough to flash into vapor, but I've never heard of this being a practical design consideration.  Maybe if the entire thing operated in a partial vacuum?

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**

(i) - Yes, correct.

(ii) - $P_2 = P_1$

[image]

**Case 2**

(i) - Yes, the flow rate is the same for both cases. No, the flow rate is constant but the velocity varies due to change in cross section ($Q = v_1A_1 = v_2A_2$).

(ii) - Again, let's write Bernoulli's equation:

$P_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 + P1 - \dfrac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2$, since $v_2 < v_1$, so $P_2 > P_1$. The result is expected based on the Bernoulli's principle, that states, with constant datum, slower moving fluids create greater pressure (force) than faster moving fluids.

Due to the presence of head, both $P_1$ & $P_2$ are not likely less than $P_{atm}$.

Comment: Thank you @r13 Case 1: ii) What about when 2 is at the end of the pipe? Will there be a sudden increase in pressure from P1 to Pout (atmospheric pressure)?

Comment: Following the release of the water, the pressure in the tank will continue to drop until there is no flow, then P1 = P2 = Patm.

Comment: Please assume the tank level is always constant what ever the flow in the pipe(infinite tank).

Comment: The pressure in the tank will change, and it is always greater than the pressure at the outlet, otherwise, backflow will occur when Patm > P2. Sorry, I don't know the case you want to build.

Comment: Yes pressure in the tank is grater than Pout and we are assuming the tank level won't vary much, say some one is putting the fluid back into the tank as flow takes place in the pipe. In your answer for case 1: ii) you mentioned P2=P1. What about when the point 2 near to the pipe outlet?

Comment: The pressure at the outlet depends on the conditions downstream - 1) Outlet open to the environment, the pressure collapses just pass the interface with quantity unknown (to me). 2) Outlet to a downstream pool - water pressure of the pool at the elevation of the outlet pipe.

Comment: let's assume the first case, that is Pout is atmospheric pressure. As you say P2=Pout. But P2=P1. Therefore P1=Pout?

Comment: Please review Bernoulli's Equation for incompressible flow with the flow rate in the pipe is constant.